# Exception attempting compile

Tags: jenkins

I am doing a build of a java application which uses jdk1.5 and maven 2.1.0. We re using Jenkins version 1.565.1.

I keep getting the below error each time I do the build and the error doesnt make any sense. Has anyone come across the error before and has successfully resolved it?

```
    [INFO] [gwt:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Exception attempting compile.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Exception attempting compile.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:703)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:540)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception attempting compile.
    at com.totsp.mavenplugin.gwt.CompileMojo.execute(CompileMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:194)
    at com.totsp.mavenplugin.gwt.AbstractGWTMojo.buildClasspathList(AbstractGWTMojo.java:345)
    at com.totsp.mavenplugin.gwt.ScriptWriterUnix.writeCompileScript(ScriptWriterUnix.java:105)
    at com.totsp.mavenplugin.gwt.CompileMojo.execute(CompileMojo.java:63)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Can you successfully build your application on build server without `Jenkins`?

Comment: Yes. We did compile and upload to the maven repository from our local machines. Apologies for the delayed reply.